# ActiveRecord - How to join association with pure SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading, model-associations

I'm doing the following query:

```
TaskCheck.find_by_sql ["SELECT task_checks.*, tasks.* FROM task_checks INNER JOIN tasks ON task_checks.task_id = tasks.id"]
```

It returns TaskCheck objects but when I try to read a Task field(joined in the query) then  ActiveRecord does a separate select query for each object. It's lazy loading my association even if I'm joining it. How do I fix that?

PS: I want to use pure SQL. The reason is because AR "includes" method executes a second SELECT for the association which is inneficient for a one-to-one association and I want the best perfomance possible.

Comment: This is so simple if you don't use pure SQL. Why use pure sql?

Comment: Because this part of the system will be executed thousand of times a day and I want the best perfomance possible.

Comment: And I remember now, the main reason is because AR "includes" method does a separate SELECT for the association. That is a good approach for Rails and a one-to-many association, but not effective in a one-to-one association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way where u can specify the columns you want, like this:

```
sql = "SELECT task_checks.*, tasks.* FROM task_checks INNER JOIN tasks ON task_checks.task_id = tasks.id"
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Then, records_array will contain all returning rows with the specified columns in the select query.